# Service account - access through API

Tags: api, kubernetes, token, role

I created a namespace `xxx`; the role for this namespace is to get pods, services, etc. I created a service account `yyy` and a role binding `yyy` to the role in namespace `xxx`.

When I try to check something through the API with a secret token, for example

```
curl -kD - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/xxx/pods
```

I get a "403 forbidden" error.

So I a cluster role binding of my service account `yyy` to cluster role `view`, and after that of course a user can see pods of my namespace, but can see other pods from other namespaces too.

How can I restrict service account `yyy` tee see pods, services, etc. only from a specific namespace?

Answer (score 1):

To allow access only in a specific namespace create a rolebinding, not a clusterrolebinding:

`kubectl create rolebinding my-viewer --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=xxx:yyy -n xxx`